# Do I need a transit visa for my connecting flight in Canada?

Tags: canada, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, connecting-flights

I am a Pakistani national, and I am traveling to Jamaica via Canada. I have a valid visa for Jamaica and need to catch my connecting flight from Canada without leaving airport international zone. Do I need visa to get my connection?

Comment: There is no "international zone". Once you arrive in Canada you must enter Canada, or go through US preclearance (if transiting to the US; doesn't apply to your case).